Sorting Two Ranges with Key Lists
I need to sort two ranges, "I" and "K". I have the next column over J for I, and L for K with formulas to produce 1-6 on the entries of the I and K ranges, so I need to sort on those numbers. Here's the code I have that is saying the range is nothing for some reason.
    Sub SortDataIK()
    
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim lastRowI As Long
        Dim lastRowk As Long
        Dim sortRangeI As Range
        Dim sortRangek As Range
        
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
        
        lastRowI = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).row
        lastRowk = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).row
         
        Set sortRangeI = ws.Range("I1:J" & lastRow)
        sortRange.Sort Key1:=ws.Range("J1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
        
        Set sortRangek = ws.Range("K1:L" & lastRow)
        sortRange.Sort Key1:=ws.Range("L1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo


    End Sub


sortRange.Sort you haven't declared sortRange or assigned any range to it.  Add Option Explicit to the top of your module and fix anything it flags up.

Erros are in lines
        Set sortRangeI = ws.Range("I1:J" & lastRow)
        sortRange.Sort Key1:=ws.Range("J1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
        
        Set sortRangek = ws.Range("K1:L" & lastRow)
        sortRange.Sort Key1:=ws.Range("L1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

No value is assigned to lastrow, it gives 0. The same for  sortRange, it gives Nothing. Evidently, it should be
        Set sortRangeI = ws.Range("I1:J" & lastRowI)
        sortRangeI.Sort Key1:=ws.Range("J1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
        
        Set sortRangek = ws.Range("K1:L" & lastRowk)
        sortRangek.Sort Key1:=ws.Range("L1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

Or
        Dim sortRange As Range
        Set sortRange = ws.Range("I1:J" & lastRowI)
        sortRange.Sort Key1:=ws.Range("J1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
        
        Set sortRange = ws.Range("K1:L" & lastRowk)
        sortRange.Sort Key1:=ws.Range("L1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

To avoid such errors, set 'Require Variable Declaration' in 'Tools-->Options'

